# how to display my method from component to html on angular

Tags: html, angular, components

there is my component -

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  private _user!: Observable<User | null>;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._user = this.authService
      .getUserListener()
      .pipe(filter((user: User | null) => !!user));
  }

  /**
   * Getter for fullname
   * @returns fullname string
   */
  public getFullname(): Observable<string> {
    return this._user.pipe(
      map((user: User | null) => `${user?.getFullname()}`)
    );
  }
}
```

i want to display the fullname from my getFullname() in html.
what is the correct syntax.

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AsyncPipe` is great for passing observables to the template. No need to manually subscribe, unsubscribe, or trigger change detection (if you're using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, which I do always recommend).

Combined with `as`, you can use the current value coming from the observable stream.

```
<div *ngIf="getFullName() | async as fullName">
  {{ fullName }}
</div>
```

Calling methods in templates is bad practice though. The method will be called again and again on every Change Detection, for no reason. Better way:

```
// component.ts

_user = this.authService
    .getUserListener()
    .pipe(
       filter((user: User | null) => !!user),
       shareReplay(1) // Prevent multiple API calls 
       // if there are multiple subscribers
    );

userName$ = this._user.pipe(
    map((user: User | null) => `${user?.getFullname()}`)
)
// I like the `$` notation to easily see that
// this is an observable ($ for stream)
```

```
<!-- component.html -->

<div *ngIf="userName$ | async as userName"> {{ userName }} </div>
```

Comment: And if you prefer not to use `*ngIf` so that the `div` exists wether or not `userName` is truthy, you can say `<div> {{ (userName$ | async) || '' }} </div>`

Comment: i tried to use the better way you gave. and i got that error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined.

Comment: Oops yeah sorry, _user was defined later in `ngOnInit`. Edited. Should be assigned before userName$ is assigned.